# Index Match or Vlookup in a Power Query

Tags: sql, excel, powerquery

I am trying to build a query that populates data in a column in a similar way to how an index, match or vlookup works.

My workbook has 2 sheets:

1. Contains open order data pulled from SQL (SQL_Data)
2. Contains saved comments that were manually entered on the SQL sheet (Preserved_Comments)

I have two queries set up:

1. Saves the order number and the manually input comments from the SQL_Data sheet, and puts them in a table on the Preserved_Comments Sheet
2. Refreshes the SQL data table

I have been trying to add a 3rd query that adds the comment column back into the SQL_Data sheet, but I can't figure out how to do a join / index, match / Vlookup that looks at the order numbers and populates the saved comment.

My goal for this is to create an order report where when the SQL data is refreshed, the manually added comments are saved and follow the order number.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Don't use a vlookup, but instead for the 3rd query you can merge the tables using whatever your shared unique identifier is to pull in the preserved comment. Similar to how you connect to the SQL table, you can connect to *that* table (or another) in your spreadsheet. If you don't have a unique identifier in the table or it's multiple, consider combining multiple columns into one to create a unique key. Doing the "vlookup" in the query level should keep things clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge both Queries into a new one. Use a key column, It would be the lookup array in INDEX/MATCH. This should allow you to join the column.